# How to properly implement multiprocessing in an application with 4 different functions?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

Have a look at the code snippet below. In the `main` function I instantiate an array `jobs`. `Projects` is an array containing multiple `project` objects. Those `project` objects also contain multiple `target` objects. For each target I want to execute four different functions. For this I start a `Process` pointing to the function `run`. I append the `Process` to the array and start it. Current piece of code will produce zombie processes which I try to avoid.

```
def main():
    jobs = []
    for project in projects:
        for target in project.getTargets():
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=run, args=(target.getX(),  
                                                          target.getY(),))
            jobs.append(p)
            p.start()

        for job in jobs:
            job.join()

def run(x, y):
    a(x, y)
    b(x, y)
    c(x, y)
    d(x, y)
```

The goal is to handle approx. five targets in parallel and then use a mechanism such as FIFO to handle a new target once a another target has finished.

Comment: Your code is somewhat confusing. You don't seem to be using `target`. Is it suposed to be split into `x` and `y`? The return values of the functions `a` upto `d` aren't used. What's the point of calling them? Normally I would suggest using a `multiprocessing.Pool` to apply a function to an iterable of values in parallel, but I'm not sure how that would fit here.

Comment: I edited the code sample to show how `target` is being used. The purpose of the functions `a` to `d` are not relevant in this case I guess. You only should know I execute a bash command inside these functions.

Comment: Apparently this is just pseudo code for some hypothetical question? 9 times out of 10 in multitasking the problem is how to split tasks and targets properly. Some function needs a lot of ram, another waits 90% of time for hard disk reads and one is busy calculating floats - or waiting input from other function. In general, start with least amount of tasks and targets and test in practise what happens and how/where the time is spent when running a certain task. Does more CPU help, or will one thread do as your ram is full or HD slow?

Answer (score 0):

Pass processing function as part your collection over which you iterate:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def fun(*args)
    proc, p, q = args
    return proc(p, q)

data = [(f, x, y) for f in (a, b, c, d)]
pool = Pool(4)
results = pool.map(fun, data)
```

Answer (score 0):

From you comment I gather that you are calling `bash` in the functions `a` .. `d`. I would suggest *not* to do that.

1. If you are doing calculations in `bash`, that's beter done in Python.
2. If you use `bash` to start programs, that is also better done directly in Python.

If you can use python 3, I would recommend to use `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` to have a bunch of threads iterate over your data. In each thread, you can then use the `subprocess` module to start external programs.
My [dicom2jpg.py](https://github.com/rsmith-nl/scripts/blob/master/dicom2png.py) script is an example how to do this. It runs ImageMagick's `convert` program in parallel to convert DICOM x-ray images into PNG format.

If you need to use Python 2.7, then I would make a list of subprocesses (by calling `subprocess.Popen`). Continuously iterate over this list and check if a subprocess has finished. If so, remove it from the list. If you have not run out of tasks, start a new subprocess and append it to the list. The list should have as many subprocesses as your machine has cores. More is generally not useful.
This approach is shown in an [older version of `dicom2png.py`](https://github.com/rsmith-nl/scripts/blob/4b8815fb9ebb8331206da67cde4964c92a168f47/dicom2png.py).

Comment: Interesting! But how would you handle this if you have like three other functions next to `startconvert`? I'm talking about Python 2.7.

Comment: @ssd As long as those other functions can have the same interface as `startconvert`, that is they take one filename argument and return a `(str, Process)` tuple, it would be OK. They would fit into the `manageprocs` framework.